# Is there a way to parser a SQL query to pull out the column names and table names?

Tags: sql, parsing

I have 150+ SQL queries in separate text files that I need to analyze (just the actual SQL code, not the data results) in order to identify all column names and table names used. Preferably with the number of times each column and table makes an appearance. Writing a brand new SQL parsing program is trickier than is seems, with nested SELECT statements and the like.

There has to be a program, or code out there that does this (or something close to this), but I have not found it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I actually ended up using a tool called 
[SQL Pretty Printer](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). You can purchase a desktop version, but I just used the free online application. Just copy the query into the text box, set the Output to "List DB Object" and click the Format SQL button.

It work great using around 150 different (and complex) SQL queries.

Answer (score 4):

How about using the Execution Plan report in MS SQLServer? You can save this to an xml file which can then be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to looking to something like this:

[JSqlParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net)

which uses JavaCC to parse and return the query string as an object graph.  I've never used it, so I can't vouch for its quality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're application needs to do it, and has access to a database that has the tables etc, you could run something like:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM MY_TABLE
```

Using ADO.NET.  This would give you a DataTable instance for which you could query the columns and their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Please go with antlr... Write a grammar n follow the steps..which is given in antlr site..eventually you will get AST(abstract syntax tree). For the given query... we can traverse through this and bring all table ,column which is present in the query..

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 you can append your query with something such as the following, but 1 is the minimum you can specify; it will throw an error if you try to specify 0:

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SDK of FlowHigh. One of the FlowHigh components is an online SQL parser. You can use it to programmatically retrieve all of the columns and tables of an SQL query.

Below is a code example in Python on how you would achieve this. And here is a link for some more [examples of SQL parsing](https://sonra.io/sql-parser/sql-parser-use-cases/#examples) through the browser or the SDK

```
import pandas as pd

from flowhigh.model import *
from flowhigh.utils import FlowHighSubmissionClass


"""
This Snippet shows how to use the SDK to collect the table list and their columns
"""

def collect_ds_hierarchy(source_obj: TreeNode):
"""
Recursively collect the Ds objects and their attributes or expressions
:param source_obj: TreeNode in hierarchy to be visited
:return:
"""
# filter only Dataset nodes
if not source_obj:
    return
if isinstance(source_obj, Ds) and source_obj.out and source_obj.type_ != 'root':
    ds: Ds = source_obj
    if getattr(source_obj, 'refTo', None):
        # ctes are in separate branches of the parsed tree
        ds = fh.search_node_by_pos(source_obj.refTo)
    # Ds -> [list of out attributes and expressions]
    accum.setdefault(ds, set()).update(ds.out.exprs)
for child in source_obj.get_children():
    collect_ds_hierarchy(child)


def collect_DBO_hierarchy(source_obj: DBO):
"""
Recursively collect the list of Database objects
:param source_obj: DBO in hierarchy to be visited
:return:
"""
if not source_obj:
    return
if source_obj.type_ == "TABLE":
    # Ds -> [list of out attributes and expressions]
    accum.setdefault(source_obj.name.upper(), set()).update([col.name for col in source_obj.dbo])
    return

for child in source_obj.dbo:
    collect_DBO_hierarchy(child)


def aggregate(agg: dict):
"""
Aggregate the collected info in a pandas dataframe
:param agg: the dictionary with the list of Ds and their columns
:return: a new Pandas Dataframe
"""
rows = []
for k, v in agg.items():
    ds_name = k.alias or k.fullref      # ds name
    ds_type = k.type_                   # ds type (e.g. root/cte/...)
    ds_subtype = k.subType              # ds subtype (e.g. inline/physical/pseudo/...)
    attr_names = [fh.get_node_raw_text(col) or col.alias or col.refatt for col in v]  # attr name
    rows.append((ds_name, ds_type, ds_subtype, attr_names))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows)
return df


# Your SQL query from editor
sql = """%sqlEditor%"""

# Initializing the SDK
fh = FlowHighSubmissionClass.from_sql(sql)

accum = []
# collect list of physical objects
for dbo in fh.get_DBO_hierarchy():
collect_DBO_hierarchy(dbo)

# loop over the list of input Statements
# and collect list of other `ds` and their attributes
for statement in fh.get_statements():
collect_ds_hierarchy(statement)

print(aggregate(accum))
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind FlowHigh. FlowHigh is a toolbox for SQL data engineers